# Proper handling of date operations in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

I am using AWS Neptune Gremlin with `gremlin_python`.

My date in property is stored as datetime as required in [Neptune specs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html).

I created it using Python code like this:
`properties_dict['my_date'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(my_date, timezone.utc)`
and then constructed the Vertex with properties:

```
for prop in properties:
    query += """.property("%s", "%s")"""%(prop, properties[prop])
```

Later when interacting with the constructed graph, I am only able to find the vertices by an exact string matching query like the following:
`g.V().hasLabel('Object').has("my_date", "2017-12-01 00:00:00+00:00").valueMap(True).limit(3).toList()`

What's the best way for dealing with date or datetime in Gremlin?
How can I do range queries such as *"give me all Vertices that have date in year 2017"*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to store date/time values as days/seconds/milliseconds since epoch. This will definitely work on any Graph DB and makes range queries much simpler. Also, the conversion to days or seconds since epoch and back should be a simple method call in pretty much any language.

So, when you create your properties dictionary, you could simplify your code by changing it to:

```
properties_dict['my_date'] = my_date
```

... as `my_date` should represent the number of seconds since epoch. And a range query would be as simple as:

```
g.V().has("Object", "my_date", P.between(startTimestamp, endTimestamp)).
  limit(3).valueMap(True)
```

Comment: with this approach you can do range queries on the integer stored in the property, or is it stored as string? Can you please explain with a simple example query?

Comment: Exactly, you only deal with Integers then.